# How to query a user by username on controller level?

Tags: users, controller

How to query a user by username on controller level?

In twig I can do:

```
{% set user = craft.users.username('username') %}
```

How to do that in controller?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query for it like

```
use craft\elements\User;

$user = User::find()->username('username')->one();
```

You can also get the currently logged-in user like:

```
use Craft;

$currentUser = Craft::$app->getUser()->getIdentity();
```